# How to reference value declared in cc:attribute in cc:implementation

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have a simple JSF 2.0 composite component example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
    <title>
        A panel box component
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="model" required="true" type="at.test.Person"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:inputText value="#{model.vorname}">

        </h:inputText>
    </cc:implementation>
</body>
```

And here is my JSF test page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:mc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mygourmet" >

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <mc:inputTest model="#{person}">

    </mc:inputTest>
    <h:commandButton value=""/>
    <h:outputText value="#{person.vorname}"/>
</h:form>
 </h:body>

</html>
```

I want that my composite component saves a string value in a JSF session bean with `<h:inputText>`. But the problem is, when I submit the form with the `<h:commandButton>` I see the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/mygourmet/inputTest.xhtml      at line 18 and column 42 value="#{model.vorname}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'model' resolved to null
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit._SharedRendererUtils.findUIOutputConverter(_SharedRendererUtils.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference composite component attribute values by `#{cc.attrs.<name>}` where `<name>` is the attribute name. So, this should do:

```
<h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.model.vorname}">
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Facelets - Composite Components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Advanced Composite Components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhxa.html)
- [`<composite:xxx>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, all that `<html><head><body>` in the composite is unnecessary. I suggest to use `<ui:component>` since that's more clear. See also [our composite component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) for examples.